# How Can I Fix a Visio Org Chart text layer in a shape

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am working on the org chart and the text layer from the Shape stencils no longer works.

[image: When I drag from the Shapes it looks correct]

After letting go onto the document it does this:

[image: After dropping this is the appearance in my document]

Lastly, if I try to delete the text, it won't let me, despite removing all protections from the developer tab.

[image: Deletion attempt]

This problem is happening for all organizational chart shapes; executive, manager, position, ... This happened recently, where it would also change my font from Helvetica to something different and only way around it was to copy and paste another *working* position, and edit it with the new employee data.

I am at a loss why this is occurring and don't know how to fix it.  Any ideas what is wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Which version of Visio?

Comment: 2013.  Extra space because rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Visio 2013 so can't help with exact menu instructions, but on the Org Chart menu you need to find Options (it might be well hidden on one of the little drop down arrows). You will be able to change which fields are shown.

You can't delete the text, change the field entry via the shape's Shape Data (you will need to open the Shape Data window).